# Simplify the following transformed equation

Tags: functions, simplifying-expressions

y=7f(-1/6(x-1))+1

The base function is f(x)=x^2. I just don't understand where the ^2 went and how to simplify this. Any help is much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: If this is about *Mathematica*, the basic syntax is `f[x]`, not `f(x)`.  Note the difference between `=` and `==` (`Set` and `Equal` in the documentation).

Comment: `Clear[f]; f[x_] = x^2; 7f[-1/6(x-1)]+1 // Simplify`

Answer (score 1):

Your variable is not gone, but otherwise noted. I think you should ask your question on [Math](https://math.stackexchange.com/). That said, you will find answers to your questions:

[How to | Create Definitions for Variables and Functions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/CreateDefinitionsForVariablesAndFunctions.html)

[Defining Variables](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DefiningVariables.html)

[Defining Functions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DefiningFunctions.html)

Just hit F1 and find the Help-Center, if your question ist about the software Mathematica, else as on [Math](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

```
f[x_] = x^2
```

> x^2

```
myEqu = 7 f[-1/6 (x - 1)] + 1
```

> 1 + 7/36 (1 - x)^2

```
Simplify[myEqu]
```

> 1 + 7/36 (-1 + x)^2

```
Plot[{f[x], myEqu}, {x, -2, 2}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you not use `f[x_] := x^2`?

Comment: @m_goldberg, I thought the OP it can look up the links and find out by him/her self.

Comment: You are more optimistic than I am.

Comment: @m_goldberg, well yes, It has some fine people in this forum, so never give up, see for [Fun-Facts](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=optimistic)

Comment: Whoa, chill, people. I was directed to this website in my quest for help so sue me if I don't know the workings of it quite yet (or don't, you know).

Comment: @Nikki, Well at least you have found help and answer, no?

Comment: @m_goldberg, i'm fooled again, shame on me.